# Mongodb build is huge

Tags: mongodb

I need to build mongodb from source to get SSL support.

I ran the following set of commands as per various sources I could find:

```
sudo git clone git://github.com/mongodb/mongo.git
cd mongo/
git checkout r2.6.0
sudo git checkout r2.6.0
sudo scons --ssl all
```

This builds without major issues (although it takes a *long* time) but the output files are huge:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 361M May  2 12:28 bsondump
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 148M May  1 15:07 mongo
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 359M May  2 12:54 mongobridge
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 365M May  2 10:30 mongod
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 362M May  2 11:21 mongodump
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 361M May  2 11:40 mongoexport
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 362M May  2 12:21 mongofiles
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 361M May  2 11:48 mongoimport
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 361M May  2 12:13 mongooplog
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 358M May  2 12:35 mongoperf
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 362M May  2 11:30 mongorestore
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 248M May  2 11:07 mongos
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 362M May  2 11:57 mongostat
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 361M May  2 12:04 mongotop
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 361M May  2 12:46 perftest
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 455M May  2 14:54 test
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The raw build produces binaries that contain the debug symbols and you can get rid of them by using the strip command like this:

```
strip mongod
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it would be something simple like that. And `scons ... install` runs strip anyway.